# Azure Bot from Sample - Error while testing

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I am trying the steps from below and I am able to deploy the bot, but it's failing on test with errors from IIS. Definetly I am missing some step so checking to see if anyone has worked on a javascript or typescript bot which they were able to deploy and can give some pointers?

I am trying this sample: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/02.echo-bot

Steps I followed to deploy the bot:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-and-publish-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Ccsharp

I am using Managed Identity and getting errors like below when I try the bot through web chat and also via teams channel.

Attached are the errors:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0fwN.png)

Built bot from samples.
Deployed Bot to Azure.
Testing bot via web chat - getting error

```
Wed Aug 02 2023 02:15:36 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:ReferenceError: FinalizationRegistry is not definedat Object.<anonymous> (C:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\on-exit-leak-free\index.js:11:18)at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)at Object.<anonymous> (C:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\pino\lib\tools.js:8:16)


</head><body><div id="content"><div class="content-container"><h3>HTTP Error 500.1002 - Internal Server Error</h3><h4>The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.</h4></div><div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4><ul> <li>IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.</li>            <li>IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.</li>                <li>IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.</li>                 <li>The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.</li>              <li>The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.</li> </ul></fieldset></div><div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4><ul>                <li>Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.</li>    <li>Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.</li>             <li>Verify the permissions for the DLL.</li>           <li>Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.</li>     <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439>here</a>. </li> </ul></fieldset></div>
```

##### Detailed Error Information:

Module   iisnodeNotification   ExecuteRequestHandlerHandler   iisnodeError Code   0x00000002
Requested URL   https://idc-bot-app-name:80/index.jsPhysical Path   C:\home\site\wwwroot\index.jsLogon Method   AnonymousLogon User   Anonymous

##### More Information:

This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.

View more information »

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

Comment: As the app service and deployment are done automatically, I am not sure how can I configure IIS or the permissions on it myself. Please suggest.

Comment: Some things to check. Have you included the `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword` in your bot's app service configuration? Be sure the key (name) of each matches the key used in the .env file. Also, verify both values are correct. Double check all the required keys/values are in the .env file. If you are unsure, then compare against the BotBuilder-Samples repo. Check that the Managed Identity is correctly setup. Do any of these help?

Comment: Thank you @StevenKanberg. I did make some progress after lot of trial and error. The ids were all fine but seems the Windows app service was getting built with node 0.10v (I don’t know why). So I went about changing the app service node version to ~16 and now I am past that error but on a diff error. I think its related to something on web.config. Meanwhile I tried the ms team extn and the dotnet sample & that worked out fine. Right now tryint to get past the new error on node sample. Will update this thread once I get it all running. Thanks again!